# FormatException with DatePicker on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8, datepicker

I've ran into a strange problem while working with DatePickers and trying to format the returned value into a format that I could use in my SQLite database. The DatePicker returns a value something like "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", but I'd like to change this value so it's in the format of "yyyy-MM-dd".

I had an issue doing this and posted on here and ended up solving the problem, but over the weekend it's stopped working without changing any of the code that previously worked. All it does now is give me the following; System.FormatException with the message "string was not recognized as a valid datetime". That's what I find strange, that it's giving me that exception even though what I was doing previously worked, and most solutions use the way I was doing it as well.

```
DateTime formatStartDate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
string fsd = formatStartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime formatEndDate = DateTime.Parse(EndDate);
string fed = formatEndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

The above code snippet worked for me and inserted into the database in the "yyyy-MM-dd" format. After getting the exception that I mentioned, I looked around for another solution to this and tried the following, which also gave me the same exception;

```
string start = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string end = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I just don't understand what the problem is. Surely it can't be this difficult to change a string pattern taken from a DatePicker to a different format? And I don't understand what was once working only a few days ago, has suddenly stopped working when nothing in that class or other classes has been touched since.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Anything change in your database?

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `DateTime.Parse` or `Convert.ToDateTime`. I think it's attempting to parse the date using `MM/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/yyy`.

Comment: Krillgar, nothing. The solution hasn't been opened since Friday which when I closed it, all this worked perfectly fine. Only today when I opened the solution and ran it and it's been giving me this issue. It's a headache.

Comment: Dai, I've tried the following;
DateTime formatStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime formatEndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string start = formatStartDate.ToString();
string end = formatEndDate.ToString(); 
But it's still giving me the same exception.

Comment: Fixed the problem. Still don't understand how something works then suddenly stops working without being touched, though. WP development is a headache.

Comment: Are the columns in  your database DateTime or VarChar?  If they are DateTime, there is no need to try to convert the format because they are not stored in any format.  Just use DateTime variables and parameterized sql queries and you won't have any issues.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a DateTime datatype, so they need to be stored as strings (or Text). Then to use DateTime properties with the DatePicker you need converters, etc. I fixed the problem eventually (below).

Answer (score 0):

```
string start = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string end = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Solved the problem.